# Cannot install Dynamics Crm 2016 on Windows 10

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I want to learn Dynamic Crm so I was trying to install it on my computer.

I have Windows 10 operating system.
When trying to install Dynamics Crm 2016 on my computer, by executing the SetupServer.exe program, I'm getting the following error message:

> --------------------------- Microsoft Dynamics CRM Setup
>   --------------------------- The computer is running an operating system that Microsoft Dynamics CRM does not support. To install this
>   product, you must upgrade your computer to a supported operating
>   system. For a complete list of supported operating systems, see the
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM documentation
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=510711).

Isn't Dynamics Crm compatible with Windows 10?
The list on the link is of Windows server operating systems; there is no mentioning of an OS that is farmiliar to me...
So how should I install it?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699671.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not install CRM 2016 on 'normal' Windows. [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699671(v=crm.7).aspx) is list of supported systems. You can always install Windows Server on virtual machine that is running on Windows 10.

Comment: So does that mean I should install VS and SQL Server on this virtual machine?

Comment: No, SQL and VS can be on different machines

Comment: Can you recommend me a website that can guide you how to install it with Sql server on the local real machine (not the virtual one)?

Comment: During CRM installation you will be promped for SQL server instance name. Remember that both machines must be in the same domain.